# c# vb: do we really need System.Lazy?

Tags: .net, static-classes

Do we really need `System.Lazy`? Let's say my class library have 100 static classes and each static class uses an average of 100 static System.Lazys = 10000 System.Lazys that have to be initiated when a program that uses my class library starts?

I mean we usually don't only use 1 class library, say we import 15 .dlls each of them have a ton of static System.Lazys.. I'm pretty sure its gonna take a long time initiating all those System.Lazys, not to mention its gonna hoard a ton of memory as well (since each have its own System.Func let's put it at 50 bytes each =500kb in memory)

So I was wondering.. is it best to just do it the "old" way (like using a boolean to keep track of whether something is initated)

Comment: what makes you "pretty sure" there is a performance penalty? Have you measured it?

Comment: Nothing like using an OOP language for procedural programming with 100 static classes... Just like doing OOP in Haskell; its a bad idea.

Comment: @jeroenh nop, but i'm thinking if i should be using Lazys for static classes at all

Comment: @mathepic so are static classes bad? i believe the entire .net library has more than a thousand static classes.. (correct me if im wrong)

Comment: @Pacerier Well are static classes the only thing inside the library? (Thats what I got from reading)

Comment: @mathepic nop.. from your previous comment i'd thought you mean 100 static classes is impossible, or "if you have 100 static classes you are doing something wrong". hence my reply

Comment: There are *much* bigger things to worry about when you have ten thousand global variables in a program.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should only use `Lazy` if 1) there's a good chance the instance won't be needed, and 2) the cost of spinning up the instance is high enough to justify the overhead.

If you have 100 static lazy members in a class, you're almost certainly doing it wrong.

Comment: Here's a great example of WHY Lazy makes sense - because doing things CORRECTLY, and MANUALLY (without Lazy) is much harder than it looks:
http://geekswithblogs.net/BlackRabbitCoder/archive/2010/05/19/c-system.lazylttgt-and-the-singleton-design-pattern.aspx

Comment: I guess my answer doesn't spell it out, but you absolutely should use `Lazy` instead of implementing thread-safe lazy instantiation yourself. If thread safety isn't important and the profiler suggests `Lazy` is problematic (which seems unlikely) then the "old way" may be better. But most importantly: if 100 properties of a single class need to be lazy, that's probably a code smell.

Answer (score 3):

As the others have said, you have much bigger problems if you need this kind of lazy initialization.

But anyway, just to show how you should be handling this question yourself: MEASURE before making assumptions.

The program below (inspired by [ayende](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2011/04/14/performance-numbers-in-the-pub.aspx)) measures the overhead of creating and initializing a Lazy() instance that simply allocates a new object.

output on my machine:

```
Created 583599 objects in 00:00:01.0000117
Created 679939 objects in 00:00:01.0039926
Created 688751 objects in 00:00:01.0000013
Created 678244 objects in 00:00:01.0000018
Created 682506 objects in 00:00:01.0000018
Created and initialized 516400 lazy objects in 00:00:01.0000018
Created and initialized 526585 lazy objects in 00:00:01.0000049
Created and initialized 519425 lazy objects in 00:00:01.0000018
Created and initialized 514477 lazy objects in 00:00:01.0000022
Created and initialized 523544 lazy objects in 00:00:01.0005176
Performance loss: 21,5091944284387 %
```

Don't draw general conclusions from this because performance problems are many times very specific to the situation at hand.

But as you can see, the overhead of instantiating an object via `Lazy` vs. simply allocating it through `new` is relatively small, given that `Lazy` should be typically in situations where delayed instantiation is useful (i.e. expensive, and the object constructed has a good chance of not being actually needed)

```
class Program
{
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var sequence = Enumerable.Range(1, 5);

        var q1 = from s in sequence
                 select GenerateSimpleObjects();

        var q2 = from s in sequence
                 select GenerateAndInitializeLazies();

        var m1 = q1.Average();
        var m2 = q2.Average();

        Console.WriteLine("Performance loss: {0} %", 100 - 100 * m2/m1);

    }

    static void GenerateSimpleObjects()
    {
        var sp = Stopwatch.StartNew();

        int i = 0;
        while (sp.ElapsedMilliseconds < 1000)
        {
            new object();
            i++;
        }
        sp.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("Created {0} objects in {1}", i, sp.Elapsed);
    }


    static void GenerateAndInitializeLazies()
    {
        var sp = Stopwatch.StartNew();

        int i = 0;
        while (sp.ElapsedMilliseconds < 1000)
        {
            var l = new Lazy<object>(() => new object());
            var o = l.Value;
            i++;
        }
        sp.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("Created and initialized {0} lazy objects in {1}", i, sp.Elapsed);
    }
}
```

Comment: actually the overhead i was talking about is not "speed" but memory. if each were to take 50 bytes and there's 10k that's already 500kb of memory

Comment: your words: "I'm pretty sure its gonna take a long time initiating all those System.Lazys, not to mention its gonna hoard a ton of memory as well". First focus on that sentence as I read it is about performance... And about memory usage: that's also easily assessed with a simple calculation or experiment.

Answer (score 2):

`Lazy<T>` is meant to be used sparingly, where it makes sense to lazy load objects in a graph. That is, for objects that are *likely* not needed, but *may* be, and if the cost for fetching them is high.

For that, they are a great solution.

If you *know* you will be using all of the objects, don't use `Lazy<T>`.

Comment: am i right to say Lazy<T> has its overheads (which are not negligible, with regards to the amounts of classes we use in typical programs)

Comment: Lazy adds two kinds of overhead: extra instance in memory (not much), and extra processing to maintain the singleton. If you choose a thread-safe `LazyThreadSafetyMode`, the extra processing will be even higher. All that said, you'll only know how these costs affect your application if you profile - they are likely insignificant compared to slow stuff like I/O.